# Intel Compute Stick Ubuntu Server 19.10 with Wifi

Tags: server, wireless, 19.10, computestick

Hey I recently bought a Intel compute stick STK1A8LFC as a minecraft bedrock server. I don't have any connection currently. I've manually installed net-tools via a usb and dpkg. Whenever i try to connect to a network(ifconfig wlan0 essid name key password), it responds with Hostname lookup faliure.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 Server

Comment: Are you really sure `wlan0` is the name of your wireless device? How did you determine that?

Comment: lshw -c network , ifconfig the say it's disabled. Is wpa_supplican req for wpa2. the only reason i have ifconfig is i put it on a usb and dpkged it

Comment: "wpa_supplican req for wpa2." Yes, it is. Please install it. Also, please edit your question to show the result of: `iwconfig` and also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Well i've installed wpa_supplicant and it seems the service can't start. My theory from other forums is that it cant run in dbus type. wpa_ui -i wlan0 or whatever it is say it cant connect to wpa_supplicant. I will provide the items req tomorrow cause i currently dont have access. It seems it might be a polkit problem cause it keeps givig related warnings